# On Boost matrix default initialization

Tags: boost, matrix

Q1. Can anybody tell if boost `matrix` always gets initialized to `0` by default. e.g.

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> mat
```

will `mat` will, by default, hold all zeros.

Q2. Are boost`zero_matrix` read only? 
As I cannot change/edit values in it.